# how to store Axios get response to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, axios

so I have this get request

```
axios.get("/eshta")
.then(data=> console.log(data.data))
```

this returns json like this {rate: 2.5, apr: 2.8}

how can I store this json into an Dictionary object that I can use elsewhere

Comment: If you have simpler example would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse() to convert data returned into an object [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)